# Can a ISP prevent or block me from using custom DNS and force using their DNS

Tags: dns, opendns

I'm asking this because, I'm seeing my custom DNS (Open DNS, Norton Connectsafe whatever) not working. I don't know when it stopped working. But I noticed it recently. I was taking service from another ISP. That time, it was working nicely. But from the last month I have moved to another ISP. And I'm facing now DNS problems. Not problems actually. Cause I can browse any site. But that's the problem to me, when I'm using opendns family Shield, or Norton Connectsafe (Policy B) to filter out adult sites.

What I'm not getting, if they (Can) block using external DNS (There is no logical reason for that), isn't it like that, that I shouldn't be able to browse anything after changing DNS address? But that's not the case. Changing DNS address, no browsing problem , also blocking nothing. Changed it in router level (it was there from the beginning), Not working even after changing each client, mobile, pc, nowhere working,  still same. I'm struggling this for last few days.

Now I'm assuming (not sure), ISP is preventing to use Custom DNS (Not sure again). Is this possible that ISP can prevent using custom DNS?

Comment: You can use the `nslookup` command to test if a dns server is working. e.g. `nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8` will ask the dns server `8.8.8.8` for the ip of `google.com`.

Comment: I'm [trying](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/220040827-My-OpenDNS-is-not-blocking-web-sites) for several days. I can't ask there As it is not OpenDns Problem, no DNS is working. I'm thinking to ask in another thread, cause this thread has answered my question. Why DNS not working, that's another question. But I'm not getting how to ask it.
-----
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2404:6800:4001:80c::200e
          172.217.31.78 (The culprit)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, they can block custom DNS - and its fairly trivial.   All they need to do is block port 53 exiting their network (except from their nameservers - but in practice its more likely to be from their broadband IP ranges)

The logical reasons for doing this include (which I vehemently disagree with, but thats besides the point) tracking usage, forcing traffic to local caches, blocking access to certain sites, injecting adverts instead of errors for non-existent domain names.

There could theoretically also be benefits to you (prevent some kinds of malware, faster DNS resolution times for people with wrong DNS settings)

Comment: Thanks. I was searching for this 'Yes/No'. so that means, if they block port 53, generally I can't browse internet after changing their DNS, isn't it?

Comment: Yes (filll goes here)

Comment: so I know now they haven't blocked it. Cause I'm able  to browse. so the problem is in my tiny home network. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they can block port 53 or redirect all port 53 traffic back to their own DNS servers, the reasons behind forcing is described by davidgo, mainly they use it to enforce websites blockage and usage monitoring.

You can however bypass this restriction by using DNSCrypt software that encrypts DNS queries and sends it to your selected DNS server over HTTPS. The only problem with it is you have to install in each device.

Another option will be to use DNS over HTTPS on browser level with DNS servers supporting it. Google and Cloudfare do support it.
In chrome, you can enable DoH as

> To enable DoH in Chrome, start by typing or copy-pasting “chrome://flags/#dns-over-https” into the address bar and press Enter.
>   Open the drop-down menu to the right of “Secure DNS Lookups” and select “Enabled.”
>   Click the “Relaunch” button at the bottom of this page to restart Chrome and activate these changes.

[DoH in Chrome](https://www.howtogeek.com/660088/how-to-enable-dns-over-https-in-google-chrome/)

You can test on DNSleaktest.com to see which DNS servers you are using.